# Which is better ligand, PH3 or PF3?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, molecular-orbital-theory, ligand-field-theory

It confuses me that many researches pointed out different results about phosphine ligands properties (σ-donor and π-acceptor). Since both phosphine $\ce{PH3}$ and phosphorus trifluoride $\ce{PF3}$ possess similar properties, which one is the better ligand in terms of forming a stronger bond with the center metal atom?

Comment: It may depend on the metal ion. PF3 would seem to be better wuth a soft metal ion that can donate pi electrons to it. (And won't blow up if you breath on it wrong.)

Comment: It would very much help your question if you provide references or better links to at least some of the papers you are referring to in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What kind of metal center are you talking about? While all phosphines are good σ-donors and poor π-acceptors, $\ce{PF3}$ is more π-acidic than $\ce{PH3}$ because of the electron withdrawing effects of the $\ce{F-}$ substituents. The more electron-rich metal centers would then be more stabilized, theoretically, by $\ce{PF3}$ than $\ce{PH3}$ due to their ability to back-donate into the phosphine.

Hard-soft acid base theory would also suggest that the softer $\ce{PF3}$ ligand will coordinate to softer metal centers, while the $\ce{PH3}$ ligand would coordinate more easily to harder metal centers.

This is all to say, in reality, I would not want to work with either phosphine due to their dangers, but would rather work with alkyl and aryl phosphines instead. Tunability of these would be easier as well.